# ggplot, changing alpha for each "color"

Tags: r, ggplot2

A specific category has far more data points than the others so I want to make it more transparent than the others so that I can see the patterns in the other categories.

```
ggplot(aes(x = density, y = alcohol), data = redWine) +
  geom_point(aes(color = quality_factor)) +
  geom_smooth(method = 'lm')+
  scale_alpha_manual(c(0.8, 0.8, 0.1, 0.1, 0.1, 0.1))
```

quality_factor is a ordered factor with 11 levels although the subset of data that I am using utilises only 6 of the 11 levels.

I attempted to change the alpha with `scale_alpha_manual` but I am unable to get it to change the alpha level at all.

what am I doing wrong here?

Comment: You also have to add `alpha` to  `aes`.

Comment: thanks PoGibas, although I do not know why my question was down voted... thank you!

Answer (score 4):

Thanks to PoGibas for the hint, here is the solution for future reference:

```
ggplot(aes(x = density, y = alcohol), data = redWine) +
  geom_point(aes(color = quality_factor, alpha = quality_factor)) +
  geom_smooth(method = 'lm')+
  scale_alpha_manual(values = c(1, 1, 0.1, 0.1, 1, 1))
```

you have to add the alpha in the `aes` for geom_point.
As a note, you cannot add `aes` to `scale_alpha_manual`.